# Automatically translate model data according language

Tags: django, django-modeltranslation

It is possible dynamically translate model data .I'm using Django 1.10 and modeltranslation 0.12.

Comment: What do you mean like "dynamically"? Give us some examples!

Comment: I'm using three language ('hi','en','ru') in project .Whenever user submit form (fields such as topic_name, content etc ) then form data translated  according to language ('hi','en','ru').Language specific field automatically translated in my model such as topic_name_en filled with English language, topic_name_hi filled with Hindi language, topic_name_ru filled with Russian language.

Comment: So, the user will fill the translated values too? For example, when he enters a `topic_name`, will he enter all the translated values for `topic_name` or you want the user to enter one value (say English) and the other (translated) values (for the same field) get translated via Google Translate?